# how to get actual page load after replacing content by using Jquery replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project that has a html page that has links to libraries- in addition it dynamically prints part of the page with Jquery replaceWith().
The dynamically printed part includes src to images, etc.

What is happening is the images are not loaded, so the page is not rendering immediately.
I need to somehow get the equivalent of a window.onload event that tells me when the page
has loaded all that stuff, so that I start the code, etc that affects the page.

I have tried tacking it on at the end of the script- that does not seem to work-
any suggestions/ideas anyone?

I have tried window.onload, etc, I am wondering if I attach 
$("#content").ready() that would work vs load, or if I have to write a window onload inside the content that is written in by replaceWith(). I have actually tried some of this already and nothing seems to work, but I may be implementing it incorectly.
Thanks!

Comment: Is the `replaceWith` code inside an AJAX function?

Comment: Have you tried JS Promises ?

Comment: It is not inside an Ajax function, and I have not tried JS Promises yet.

Answer (score 0):

Note, No `html` , `js` appear at original post.

Try below (adjustable) pattern, i.e.g., assign different `class` to "original content" (`.ocontent`) , "new content" (`.ncontent`), check utilizing `$.is()`

```
var callback = function (status) {
    if (status === false) {
      console.log(status);
        // new content ready
        // do stuff
    };
    if (status === true) {
      console.log(status);
        // old content present
        // do stuff
    };
};

  $.when($(".ocontents").replaceWith("<img class=ncontents />"))
  .done(function(o) {
    callback($("#content *").is(o));
  });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6agJz/

See http://api.jquery.com/is/